# How to use the BigDecimal classes in C#?

Tags: c#, bigdecimal

I don't need the big integer class. I only need BigDecimal as I am working on very big decimals right now. Here is a link which I got the source code from, but it only contains BigInteger and BigFloat. I only need to work with addition, subtraction, multiplication and division of such BigDecimals. But I can't use the Big Decimal class

https://bitbucket.org/CaptainChemo/library.core/src/b063046dbd7f/Library.Core/Library.Core/DataStructures/

Comment: For which language? Some languages have them built-in, some don't, but have popular third party libraries they can use, and some simply don't have them at all.

Comment: I see the code you linked to is C#. I don't think C# has a BigDecimal type, and the library you linked to doesn't seem to have it either. You may be able to use BigFloat, I don't know. Or perhaps you can use the built-in Decimal class (for max. 28 digit decimals).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am talking about C# :) Can you please say where can I find the right Library for BigFloat. I have used decimals and doubles, but they actually are not big enough. I may need to multiply 20-25 digits of decimal numbers together. So decimal or double wont be enough. Can you also show how I can use the 4 operations using the BigFloat library, I am unable to do so.

Comment: I don't know this particular implementation, sorry.